# LoopJ Header[] error

Tags: android, android-studio, loopj

I'm trying to use `LoopJ` but it gives me an error on the `Header[]` params like on the image below. It say that I need to import the `Header` package but when I do it it gives me another error on `FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler`.

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("https://example.com/file.png", new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(/* Context */ this) {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, File file) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, File file) {

            }


        });
```

[image: image of the error]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `gradle` file you should also add this `dependency`:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
```

`Header[]` is part of `HttpCore` not `AsyncHttpClient` library.

Answer (score 2):

[The Apache http package is deprecated as of Android 6.0](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

[Instead you should use this (re)package.](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cz.msebera.android/httpclient/4.4.1.1)

if you are using gradle:

```
  dependencies {
      compile "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your lower-level `build.gradle` and import `Header[]`

```
dependencies {
     compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
}
```

Followed by newest version available

**OR**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'httpcomponents-httpcore:httpcore:4.0-alpha6'
}
```

Followed by [Gradle please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#httpcore)